# React Native slower cold boot when offline

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-hermes

I recently upgraded my react native app from 0.50.10 to 0.62.2. Everything went smoothly and I'm pretty happy with the enhanced performance Hermes provides on Android, however we found one major problem when trying to launch the app in offline mode, previous to the upgrade, if the app was offline, it would take 2 to 3 seconds to complete the start up process, now, after the update it takes up to 20 seconds to start! I'm counting only the time react native takes to load (the time the initial white screen is visible before the actual app loads).

A few more details:

- This is only happening on Android, iOS loads almost instantly when offline.
- When the app is launched in normal mode (not offline) the start up time is identical to what it was on our previous version.
- I have enabled Hermes but even when Hermes disabled, the start up time is still way higher than it was before.
- I have removed a few packages that I had the suspicion could be depending on network connections but so far I haven't been able to find a culprit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.